# Separate python tuple with newlines

Tags: python, json, tuples, twilio, urllib

I am working on a simple script that collects earthquake data and sends me a text with the info. For some reason I am not able to get my data to be separated by new lines. Im sure I am missing something easy but Im still pretty new to programming so any help is greatly appreciated! Some of the script below:

```
import urllib.request
import json
from twilio.rest import Client
import twilio

events_list = []

def main():
  #Site to pull quake json data
  urlData = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson" 
  
  webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
  
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = webUrl.read()

  # Use the json module to load the string data into a dictionary
    theJSON = json.loads(data)

  # collect the events that only have a magnitude greater than 4
    for i in theJSON["features"]:
      if i["properties"]["mag"] >= 4.0:
        events_list.append(("%2.1f" % i["properties"]["mag"], i["properties"]["place"]))

    print(events_list)
    
    # send with twilio
    body = events_list
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    if len(events_list) > 0:
      client.messages.create (
        body = body,
        to = my_phone_number,
        from_ = twilio_phone_number
      )
  else:
    print ("Received an error from server, cannot retrieve results " + str(webUrl.getcode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Do you mean in one string? `"\n".join(mytuple)`

Comment: I tried that @ti7 and got error of expecting a str so I tried: `"\n".join(str(mytuple))` 
but each char ends up on its own line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the tuple with newlines, you need to call the `"\n".join()` function. However, you need to first convert all of the elements in the tuple into strings.

The following expression should work on a given tuple:

```py
"\n".join(str(el) for el in mytuple)
```

Note that this is different from converting the entire tuple into a string. Instead, it iterates over the tuple and converts each element into its own string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the list of tuples stored in "events_list" you could probably do something like this:

```
for event in events_list:
    print(event[0],event[1])
```

It will give you something like this:

```
4.12 10km near Florida
5.00 4km near Bay
```

Comment: This works great for printing out but how do I save it that way into a new list which I can send via twilio afterwards? One thing I particularly like about this output is how clean it is. Using `final_send_list = "\n".join([str(el) for el in events_list])` I get the data but the output includes parentheses and \n

Comment: So you want a list like ["4.12 10km near Florida", "5.00 4km near Bay"] ? If so, then you can simply do this: ```events_list = [str(x[0])+' '+x[1] for x in events_list]``` this will give the output as ["4.12 10km near Florida", "5.00 4km near Bay"]

Comment: Interesting... If I use this code
`for i in theJSON["features"]:
      if i["properties"]["mag"] >= 4.0:
        events_list.append(("%2.1f" % i["properties"]["mag"], i["properties"]["place"] + "\n"))
    
    final_send_list = [str(x[0])+' '+x[1] for x in events_list]
    print(final_send_list)`

I get back: 

['4.0 10km SSE of Bombay Beach, CA\n', '4.6 12km SSE of Bombay Beach, CA\n', ]

Comment: Yeah now if you can use those lists to send it to Twilio as you wanted. Or the format that you wanted different?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to strip out the brackets and \n characters to make it look like the output in your initial print statement. Each on its own line like above

Comment: Then use ```events_list = [str(x[0])+' '+x[1] for x in events_list]``` like you already did and then you can simply do ```print(*events_list, sep='\n')``` It will give you output in new line